# How can I solve this Mysql2 gem error in CentOS 8?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, centos, centos8

I need to setup ruby on rails with MySQL

I already have installed MYSQL

when I do **Bundle install** it shows following error.

```
Fetching mysql2 0.3.21
Installing mysql2 0.3.21 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I am using Cent-os 8

anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to give more detail than that. Usually it tells you about where to look for a more detailed error report.

Answer (score 0):

Run first this command `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.21'` in terminal and when finish then try bundle again